# Duplicate results in SuperUser Search

Tags: bug, status-completed, search

I was doing a search over at SuperUser and had 6 / 50 duplicate results of *What are the best Excel tips?* appear on the first page of the following search:

> https://superuser.com/search?q=excel+drop+down

It seems to me that a distinct search would be more useful.

Answer (score 2):

The search engine is probably finding it in multiple answers to that question.

You have to remember that the search engine gets to search over the internal version of every page.